# Toggle switch in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I am enabling first button when i disable second one. this is working but not properly.
I need to double click on second button to enable second button and disable first one.
i did lot of debugging and searching but I am not find where i am going wrong. Any kind of help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

React js code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Link as LinkR} from 'react-router-dom'
import './SectionConnect.css'

const SectionConnect = () => {
  return (
    <div className="connect-container">
      <div className="connect-wrapper">
        <h2>How it works</h2>
        <p>We connect you with the very best practitioners and most effective methods to achieve optimal health.</p>
        <div className="connect-btn">
          <LinkR to='/' onClick={()=>setClick(true)} className={clicked ? 'active-btn':'disable-btn'}>
            For companies
          </LinkR>
          <LinkR to='/forIndividuals' onClick={()=>setClick(!clicked)} className={clicked ? 'disable-btn':'active-btn'}>
            For individuals
          </LinkR>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SectionConnect
```

CSS code

```
.connect-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 8px 8px 6px 10px;
  background: #FAFAFC;
  border-radius: 78px;
  width: 58%;
  height: 50px;
}

.disable-btn {
  font-family: Sofia Pro;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #435473;
  padding: 4px 8px 0px 16px;
  border-radius: 74px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active-btn {
  padding: 8px 8px 0px 16px;
  background: #5582A7;
  border-radius: 74px;
  font-family: Sofia Pro;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Although you should really be using a functional state update to toggle a boolean your code appears to function as you expect it to. https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-switch-in-reactjs-5gdcy Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you want the expected behavior to be. Are you wanting to use a single click to select/toggle the active link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) with `activeClassName` to achieve what you're after without needing to use local component state.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import './SectionConnect.css';

const SectionConnect = () => {
  return (
    <div className="connect-container">
      <div className="connect-wrapper">
        <h2>How it works</h2>
        <p>
          We connect you with the very best practitioners and most effective
          methods to achieve optimal health.
        </p>
        <div className="connect-btn">
          <NavLink
            to="/"
            exact
            activeClassName="active-btn"
            className="disable-btn"
          >
            For companies
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/forIndividuals"
            exact
            activeClassName="active-btn"
            className="disable-btn"
          >
            For individuals
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit toggle-switch-in-reactjs]